# Outlook Web Add-in: Having two DetectedEntity doesn't work for contextual detection

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Within the same outlook web addin, I'm trying to add two different contextual detection with different regular expression. (each RegEx rules match will have it's own source location.)

However, it doesn't work.
The current behavior is the first DetectedEntity is activated. However, others 
aren't.

I was wondering if it's a limitation of contextual detection.
If not, could someone please provide any example to have more than 1 DetectedEntity?

Here is my manifest:

```
....
<Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
      <DesktopFormFactor>
        <!-- DetectedEntity -->
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
          <Label resid="ContextLabel1" />
          <SourceLocation resid="DetectedURL1" />
          <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
            <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
            <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="GUID" RegExValue="[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-][0-9A-Fa-f]{12}" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" />
          </Rule>
        </ExtensionPoint>
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
          <Label resid="ContextLabel2" />
          <SourceLocation resid="DetectedURL2" />
          <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
            <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
            <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="AnotherRegEx" RegExValue="\(Test:.*\)" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" />
          </Rule>
        </ExtensionPoint>
      </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
  </Hosts>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation in contextual activation. There are two steps I would recommend for working around it.

First, the two And rules can be combined into a single detected entity using an Or rule:

```
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <!-- Additional rules -->
  </Rule>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <!-- Additional rules -->
  </Rule>
</Rule>
```

Second, while both regular expressions will launch the same source location URL, in JavaScript, it's possible to tell which expression the user selected to launch the add-in with the [item.getSelectedRegExMatches API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox.item#getselectedregexmatches--object). This API was introduced along-side the DetectedEntity extension point in Requirement Set 1.6.

getSelectedRegExMatches returns keys and values to indicate which expression and match was selected. It's possible for multiple matches to be returned if they overlap. There's an example in the documentation, but following your example, the value returned would look something like this:

```
{
  'AnotherRegEx': ['Test: match'],
  'GUID': []
}
```